# Taking user input into dataset, then check items in dataset and move to new dataset

Tags: python

I want to get a user's input of ISBN-10/ISBN-13s and be able to check the length of each input after it's put into a dataset then convert the ISBN-13s to ISBN-10s. In the end it should be a list of ISBN-10s. I'm currently getting an empty list when I try and don't know where I went wrong with my code.

```
import pyisbn

alist = []
def get_dataset():
    while True:
        try:
          dataset = [str(_) for _ in input("\nEnter Book ID(s): ").replace(',', ' ').split()]
        except ValueError:
          print("\nInvalid Input")
          continue
          
          for _ in range(0, len(dataset)):
            if len(_) == 10:
              alist.append(dataset)
            if len(_.replace('-', '')) == 13:
              alist.append(pyisbn.convert(dataset))
            
        if len(dataset) < 1:
          print("\nPlease enter at least 1 Book ID.")
        else:
          return alist

print(get_dataset())
```

I have tried moving the for loop after checking the dataset length but the code just ends after input. I have also tried putting the code outside of the try loop but then get `Object of type 'int' has no len` error. Lastly, I have tried taking everything out of the function but that doesn't seem to change any errors I get.

Comment: Usually you only use an underscore as a variable name if you are not going to use it. It's generally for throwaway values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your for loop is the problem. Try this:

```
import pyisbn

alist = []
def get_dataset():
    while True:
        try:
          dataset = [str(_) for _ in input("\nEnter Book ID(s): ").replace(',', ' ').split()]
        except ValueError:
          print("\nInvalid Input")
          continue
          
        for id_value in dataset:
          if len(id_value) == 10:
            alist.append(id_value)
          if len(id_value.replace('-', '')) == 13:
            alist.append(pyisbn.convert(id_value))
            
        if len(dataset) < 1:
          print("\nPlease enter at least 1 Book ID.")
        else:
          return alist

print(get_dataset())
```